# Que signifie "il" dans "il pleut"?

Tags: grammaire

Tout bêtement, je peux me dire que c'est un "il" général.
Quand on m'a posé la question je me suis dit qu'il doit avoir une histoire à l'origine de cette utilisation, quelle est-elle ?

> Il pleut

> Il fait froid

Comment: *it rains* - *it/il* is just a space filler or *dummy subject*, since neither English nor French allow for subject-less sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Il*** est un pronom impersonnel, ou si on veut un pronom personnel utilisé avec un verbe impersonnel.

L'histoire à l'origine de ce pronom est ancienne puisque cet usage existait déjà en ancien français, *il* vient du latin *illud* (cela, celui-là). Contrairement à l'italien ou l'espagnol, le français a très tôt été une langue où un pronom sujet était requis. Pour les verbes impersonnels comme *pleuvoir*, *venter*, *neiger*, etc. le pronom "neutre" *il* s'est imposé.

Voir [Les pronoms neutres il/ca/ça; une comparaison de leurs emplois et de leurs signifié](http://www.fondsgustaveguillaume.ulaval.ca/les-pronoms-neutres-ilceca-une-comparaison-de-leurs-emplois-et-de-leur-signifie/). Gustave Guillaume.